# customize literal control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can we change the literal button in asp.net tools? For example a literal come up and ask us a question and we can answer it by using two buttons that show us yes and no.

```
 Literal1.Text = "<script>alert('You have already sent a request for this reviewer')    </script>";
```

If it is possible please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might be looking for a confirm, rather than an alert:

```
<script>confirm('You have already sent a request for this reviewer')</script>
```

However confirm shows ok/cancel and not yes/no. If you want more control, maybe look into modal dialogs.